# How to grant FLS to an existing fields on profile basis through SOAP UI

Tags: field-level-security

How can I give field level security to the fields on **profile basis**

I have referred sample on how to update the records but I'm not sure how this helps me on giving FLS to the fields. Because I need to handle multiple conditions over here for granting FLS to filed.

```
private static void updateAccounts() {
            System.out.println("Update the 5 new test Accounts...");
            SObject[] records = new SObject[5];
            try {
              QueryResult queryResults = connection.query("SELECT Id, Name FROM Account ORDER BY " +
                    "CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 5");
              if (queryResults.getSize() > 0) {
                  for (int i=0;i<queryResults.getRecords().length;i++) {
                      SObject so = (SObject)queryResults.getRecords()[i];
                    System.out.println("Updating Id: " + so.getId() + " - Name: "+so.getField("Name"));
                    // create an sobject and only send fields to update
                    SObject soUpdate = new SObject();
                    soUpdate.setType("Account");
                    soUpdate.setId(so.getId());
                    soUpdate.setField("Name", so.getField("Name")+" -- UPDATED");
                    records[i] = soUpdate;
                  }
                }
```

Comment: This code updates *records*, not FLS. You need to use the metadata API to even get started with giving FLS.

Comment: The code you need to start from is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm).

Comment: @sfdcfox - I'm new to metadata API. One question here, Do I need to create an Apex class or do any configurations in a sandbox (where I'm going to deploy the changes) in order to use metadata API service?

Comment: No, the Metadata API can be used directly in Java. In fact, it's easier that way; writing Apex Code would add an unnecessary level of complexity for what otherwise would be straight forward code. Note that you'll need to download the Metadata WSDL (from Develop > API) and import it in to your project.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I have downloaded MetaData WSDL from Org. Now my question is, as it is a .wsdl file, how do I import this into my project

Comment: Should I need to convert wsdl to a jar file? If so can you guide me how to?

Comment: I'm not super-familiar with recent Java technology, but I guess [wsdl-to-java](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) or [axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/) would be a good starting point. You take the WSDL and convert it to Java by some means, then you can import the classes into your project and use them to call Salesforce.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Thanks and I have generated and imported metadata jar filed into my java project. But I can't invoke any of the metadatservice class members from imported the jar file. ie.                                                                                       **MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();**                              Can you help me to find out what could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use metadata api to control FLS. The following answer may help you.

[Field level security using metadata api](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159062/field-level-security-using-metadata-api)